# Как сложить две дельты времени

Tags: python, python-3.x, время, datetime

Есть база операций с акциями. У каждой есть дата в формате `2020-03-16T10:37:57.046+03:00`
По сути, есть "вход" в акцию и "выход". Нужно рассчитывать время владения.

```
t1 = datetime.fromisoformat('2020-03-30T21:49:57.046+03:00') #покупка
t2 = datetime.fromisoformat('2020-04-07T10:37:57.015+03:00') #продажа
_delta = t2-t1
print(_delta) #7 days, 12:47:59.969000
```

Ситуацию осложняют случаи вход-выход и потом снова вход-выход для одной и той же акции.
Вопрос - как можно складывать результаты из дельт: `_delta+_delta`?

Comment: Так их же можно складывать оператором `+`, как вы и написали. В чём проблема?

Comment: Спасибо! Нашел ошибку в другом месте. Думал, что я не корректно складываю. Оказалось, накосячил при работе со словарем.

Comment: перенёс в ответ

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

Дельты можно складывать встроенным оператором `+`. Так что код `_delta + _delta` должен работать.